# How to restrict compute engine to accept requests only from app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running my server on `Google App engine` where i am using `nodejs` and i have all other services like `mongoDB, Elasticsearch and Redis` deployed on `Compute engine`.

Now because of security concerns, on all database instances(MongoDB, ES, Redis) i don't want to accept requests from anywhere but only coming from `App engine`.

Is there anything i can do using `VPN OR Networks Or Firewall(Using Target tags and Source tags)` or anything to accept requests only from app engine ??

**I read about using tags in firewall section, where i can define app engine instances as source tags and compute engine tags as target tags, so that that my target tags can only listen to source tags**.

Please help me guys i am searching for this from quite a long time but haven't found anything useful.

**UPDATE**

`I tried to set my app_engine instance tag and then used that tag to the firewall rule associated with all services(MongoDB, ES, Redis) so that only services will get connected by app engine only, but it is not working now i am not able to connect to my app engine to all of my services.`

I have only one network which is `default network(auto-created by google)`, and all my instances e.g `MongoDB` as well as my `app engine` are on this same `default network`.

I added below line in app.yaml

```
network:
  instance_tag: app-tag
```

Below i sat source tag as above `app-tag` in `firewall rule` For my MongoDB database.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use app engine flexible. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/

Then set the serivce machines on the same network with the databases.

In such configuration you don't need to set public IPs to the databases so there won't be access to them from outside of the internal network.

Comment: Also `by meaning same network i want only my instances on that same network` but how can i restrict a network to contain only my instances ?? because when you create your own network, it ask for `range of ips` now if you will set something like `e.g 10.128.0.0/9` now this `network` will accept every connection on `region us-central-1`, but i want only my instances in my network not all set of ips defined on a region on google cloud ??

Comment: When you create a network, you actually create a private network. Only instances in this network have access to each other. You can use firewall in the database servers to accept traffic only from specific address ranges.

Comment: About your updated question: from the docs it looks that the source tags are applied only if you use the same network for the databases and the app engine instances.

Comment: I have only one network which is `default network(auto-created by google)`, now all my instances e.g `MongoDB` as well as my `app engine` are on this same default network, now can you please tell me why i am not able to connect my `app engine` to my `compute engine instances`. ?? Why ??

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. I have a service in App Engine Flexible (Python) deployed with a network tag. I want a node in Compute Engine to receive traffic from this service, but the Firewall rule does not work.